# Adjust outcome variable values dependent on a factor

Tags: repeated-measures, ancova

I am running an longitudinal study on electricity consumption.
I test the effect of 3 interventions on DV consumption in kWhs. For the interventions, I have a categorial dummy var with 3 levels.

I run a repeated measures ANCOVA with weekly electricity values as factor levels of the "within" factor, and regress that on the intervention dummy.

One of the factors I control for in the model is whether people live alone in their houses. I have made a binomial dummy for that, and I include it as a covariate.

However, since the actual consumption for the houses where more than 1 person lives is higher, and this contaminates the effect of my interventions, should I also adjust the actual consumption values for those participants, who live with another? Say, adjust it to the median values?

Thank you in advance.